# Mysql: Too many connections to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

recently encountered such a problem, mysql permanently crash with error "Too many connections".

Connections limit was increased(350 connections), but this not help for me.
I am use PDO with persistent connection, but still open for new connections.

In what could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: have u read this ?http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/too-many-connections.html

Comment: Thanks, @RishabhRaj, but I've read it.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by code I've seen in other questions under pdo tag, most likely you are opening new connection for the every query. So, persistent connection makes it even worse.

Create only one single connection and use it throughout whole app, and error will be gone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am use PDO, and in docs says `Many web applications will benefit from making persistent connections to database servers. Persistent connections are not closed at the end of the script, but are cached and re-used when another script requests a connection using the same credentials. The persistent connection cache allows you to avoid the overhead of establishing a new connection every time a script needs to talk to a database, resulting in a faster web application. `

Comment: My answer is not about persistent connection.

Comment: Yes, but I've use persistent connection, but by the documentation, new connections should'nt be created for every query. Maybe I do not understand your answer?

Comment: May be. But you aren't supposed to. Just follow it.